# jQuery works in Chrome and firefox, but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

First off, apologies for the poor title, but I honestly don't know enough about jQuery to be specific about what isn't working and other similarly-titled questions don't provide a working solution.

I have the following code which allows the user to select multiple options without holding down ctrl, and as the title suggests, it works fine except in IE (I'm currently using IE 11).

```
function MultiSelect()
{
    $('.select-toggle').each(function(){    
        var select = $(this), values = {};    
        $('option',select).each(function(i, option){
            values[option.value] = option.selected;        
        }).click(function(event){        
            values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
            $('option',select).each(function(i, option){            
                option.selected = values[option.value];        
            });    
        });
    });
}
```

It is being called from an html options box

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    MultiSelect();
});

<script>

</head>
<body>

...
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label for="defendants">Defendant(s):</label>
        <select class="select-toggle" name="people" id="people" multiple="multiple" >
            <option value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
            <option value="Julie Smith">Julie Smith</option>     
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: it may be working in chrome because of `multiple="multiple"` try the same in chrome after removing that. Also if possible setup a jsfiddle for your code

Comment: The `click` event on `option` elements is not supported everywhere.

Comment: What is your jQuery version? To work in IE can't be jQuery 2.x...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki jQuery 2.x works fine in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE browser does not supprot `option` click event, you need to add event on `select` element, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MultiSelect();
});
function MultiSelect()
{
    $('.select-toggle').each(function(){    
        var select = $(this), values = {};    
        $('option',select).each(function(i, option){
            values[option.value] = option.selected;        
        });
        $(this).click(function(event){        
            values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
            $('option',select).each(function(i, option){            
                option.selected = values[option.value];        
            });    
        });
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1czbL936/2/)

Comment: The demo didn't work in IE, but the code worked when actually tested. Many thanks